# how to avoid this error

Tags: asp.net

In my page, if i refer
 using System.windows.forms; 
 using System.web.webcontrols.....

Textbox ambiguos refernece error is occured from webcontrols and forms,

how can i rectify this error... but i need those two namespaces in my asp.net page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first say that I find it a bit odd that you need to reference System.Windows.Forms in an ASP.NET project.

As already posted by [ondesertverge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091818/how-to-avoid-this-error/3091839#3091839), you can fully qualify your types.  You can create aliases for the namespaces to save some typing:

```
using WebForms = System.Web.WebControls;
using WinForms = System.Windows.Forms;

// ...

var textbox = new WebForms.TextBox();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fully qualify one of them.

`System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`

Answer (score 0):

You can [alias the namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx) and uses the alias for each type:

```
using winforms = System.Windows.Forms;
using webForms = System.Web.Webcontrols;
...

     winforms::TextBox ...
     webforms::TextBox ...

...
```

Another option is to use the full name for each type (including the namespace), to avoid ambiguity.